# Quiero crear un objeto dentro de otro, pero no puedo usar adds en sprite - HaxeFlixel

Tags: javascript, game

Quiero crear una caja con una moneda, que aparece cuando la destruyo. El problema surge cuando rompo la caja, la moneda aparece pero es invisible porque no puedo hacer `add` en los *states*. ¿Cómo puedo crear la moneda de otra manera para que aparezca solo cuando destruyo la caja?

Este es el código con el que intenté resolverlo:

```
class Obstaculo extends FlxSprite{ // Base para una clase por lo que no comentare mas hasta que tenga s
    private var destructible:Int = FlxG.random.int(0, 1);
    private var dropeable:DropFalling; // esto es para asignarle un drop
    private var destructible:Int = FlxG.random.int(0, 1);
    private var danio:Int = 0;
    private var golpeado:Bool = false;
    // private var direccionDelGolpe:Bool = false; // indica la direccion del golpe para determinar vel
    private var contador:Int = 0; // ahora lo uso para saber cuanto tiempo se mueve la caja indestructi
    public function Golpeada(personaje:Jugador){
        golpeado = false;
        if (destructible == 1 && golpeado == false){
            danio += 1; //por cada golpe lastima la caja 6 veces. 3 golpes para matarla.
            contador = Reg.effectTimer - 5;
            trace ("crash");
            if (danio == 3){
                dropeable = new DropFalling(x+14, y+29);
                dropeable.SetBroken(true);
                add(dropeable); // ...?
                Reg.puntaje += 10;
                // ...
}}}}
```